# ОШИБКА: столбец user0_.id не существует

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate

Добавляю обработку исключения на случай перехода по url с неправильным id юзера. Тест срабатывает отлично, ошибка перехватывается и выбрасывается сообщение об ошибке. 
Когда запуск идет через Application то при переходя по ссылке выбрасывает ошибку

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

В свою очередь Hibernate выдает ошибку

> ОШИБКА: столбец user0_.id не существует

[image: После красной линии ошибка]

domain.User

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue()
private UUID id;
private String username;
private String email;

public UUID getId() { return id; }
public void setId(UUID id) { this.id = id; }

public String getUsername() { return username; }
public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

public String getEmail() { return email; }
public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public UserReadDTO getUser(@PathVariable UUID id){
    return userService.getUser(id);
}
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public UserReadDTO getUser(UUID id){
    User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(User.class, id);
    });
    return toRead(user);
}

private UserReadDTO toRead(User user){
    UserReadDTO dto = new UserReadDTO();
    dto.setId(user.getId());
    dto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    dto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    return dto;
}
}
```

Exception

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EntityNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public EntityNotFoundException(Class entityClass, UUID id){
        super(String.format("Entity %s with id=%s is not found", 
    entityClass.getSimpleName(), id));
    }
}
```

Comment: а пробовали над классом юзера повесить аннотацию @Table(name = "users") ? имя таблицы специально указано как "users", а не как "user", потому как "user" может быть зарезервировано системой

Comment: @Дмитрий попробовал добавить. users подчеркивает и ошибка `Cannot resolve table 'users' ` . Я только начал разбираться с этой всей темой, так что если туплю сорри(

Comment: @Дмитрий вообщем переименовал таблицу на users и добавил аннотацию как Вы и сказали. Это и помогло решить проблему. Большое спасибо!

Comment: не за что, рад , что у вас получилось))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Над классом `User` добавил аннотацию `@Table(name = "users")` и переименовал таблицу в init файле.